# Sql Query to Linq using joins

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

Actually I'm trying to convert my `SQL` Query to `Linq`.
My query contains 3 tables :

My query :

```
select ST.TEMPLATE_ID,ST.TEMPLATE_NAME,ST.CREATED_DATE
,count(distinct SQ.QUESTION_ID) as NOQ
,(
select count(*) from SURVEY_EMAIL_BLAST SEB 
where SEB.TEMPLATE_ID=ST.TEMPLATE_ID
and SEB.STATUS='Delivered'
) as [Sent]
,(
select count(*) from SURVEY_EMAIL_BLAST SEB 
where SEB.TEMPLATE_ID=ST.TEMPLATE_ID
and (SEB.EMAIL_RESULT_TEXT='Viewed' or seb.EMAIL_RESULT_TEXT='Completed')
) as [View]
,(
select count(*) from SURVEY_EMAIL_BLAST SEB 
where SEB.TEMPLATE_ID=ST.TEMPLATE_ID
and SEB.EMAIL_RESULT_TEXT='Completed'
) as [Reply]
from SURVEY_TEMPLATE ST left outer join SURVEY_QUESTION  SQ
on ST.TEMPLATE_ID=SQ.TEMPLATE_ID
group by ST.TEMPLATE_ID,ST.TEMPLATE_NAME,ST.CREATED_DATE
order by ST.TEMPLATE_ID
```

and My result is :

[image]

and My linq Query goes like this :

```
var data111 = (from st in VDC.SURVEY_TEMPLATE
               join sq in VDC.SURVEY_QUESTION on new { TEMPLATE_ID = st.TEMPLATE_ID } equals new { TEMPLATE_ID = (Int64)sq.TEMPLATE_ID } into fg
               from z in fg.DefaultIfEmpty()
               group st by new
               {
                  st.TEMPLATE_ID,
                  st.TEMPLATE_NAME,
                  st.CREATED_DATE,                                           
               } into g
               orderby
               g.Key.TEMPLATE_ID
               select new
               {
                  TEMPLATE_ID = (Int64?)g.Key.TEMPLATE_ID,
                  g.Key.TEMPLATE_NAME,
                  CREATED_DATE = (DateTime?)g.Key.CREATED_DATE,
                  Sent = (Int64?)
                  (from seb in VDC.SURVEY_EMAIL_BLAST
                   where
                  seb.SURVEY_TEMPLATE.TEMPLATE_ID == g.Key.TEMPLATE_ID &&
                    seb.STATUS == "Delivered"
                    select new
                    {
                      seb
                    }).Count(),
                  View = (Int64?)
                  (from seb in VDC.SURVEY_EMAIL_BLAST
                    where
                    seb.SURVEY_TEMPLATE.TEMPLATE_ID == g.Key.TEMPLATE_ID && (
                    seb.EMAIL_RESULT_TEXT == "Viewed" ||
                    seb.EMAIL_RESULT_TEXT == "Completed")
                    select new
                     {
                       seb
                     }).Count(),
                    Reply = (Int64?)
                     (from seb in VDC.SURVEY_EMAIL_BLAST
                       where
                       seb.SURVEY_TEMPLATE.TEMPLATE_ID == g.Key.TEMPLATE_ID &&
                       seb.EMAIL_RESULT_TEXT == "Completed"
                       select new
                        {
                          seb
                         }).Count()
                   }).ToList();
```

and Now My result is :

[image]

I'm Unable to display `NOQ` column.
Can anyone help me?

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, add `z` into `group by` source:

```
           group new { st , z } by new
           {
              st.TEMPLATE_ID,
              st.TEMPLATE_NAME,
              st.CREATED_DATE,                                           
           } into g
```

And then use it to get `NOQ` in `select`:

```
NOQ = g.Select(x => x.z.QUESTION_ID).Distinct().Count()
```

Or just replace `st` with `z`, as you're not using `st` anywhere later:

```
           group z by new
           {
              st.TEMPLATE_ID,
              st.TEMPLATE_NAME,
              st.CREATED_DATE,                                           
           } into g
```

But it will require a change in `select` as well:

```
NOQ = g.Select(x => x.QUESTION_ID).Distinct().Count()
```

And to be honest: your query looks terrible. Are you sure the same cannot be done better?

Comment: when i'm writing group new { st,sq} by new :
sq is not coming in intellisense,and error like cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Inequality comparer'

Comment: @RealSteel OK, I missed the `DefaultIfEmpty` part. Try with `z` instead of `sq`.

Comment: even i think the same way :)
I need to change my query :)